# Serial Modbus Slave doesn't respond

Tags: c#, timeout, modbus, listen

I have trouble starting a Modbus Slave through RTU.

TCP works fine but RTU seems to stop at listening stage.

I think it goes on an infinite loop(more like a hang) so I tried to look for something like timeout method but couldn't find any.

P.S.Since it's not an error, I can't handle it at catch phrase either. It just stops at that line.

```
case "TCP":
    try
    {
        TcpListener slaveTcpListener = new TcpListener(IP, Port);
        slaveTcpListener.Start();
        slave = ModbusTcpSlave.CreateTcp(SlaveID, slaveTcpListener);
        slave.DataStore = DataStoreFactory.CreateDefaultDataStore(MaxCoil, MaxDI, MaxHR, MaxIR);
        slave.DataStore.DataStoreReadFrom += new EventHandler<DataStoreEventArgs>(dataStore_DataStoreReadFrom);
        slave.ModbusSlaveRequestReceived += Slave_ModbusSlaveRequestReceived;

        slave.Listen();

        ReadShm.IsBackground = true;
        ReadShm.Start();
    }
    catch
    {

    }
case "RTU":
    try
    {
        SerialPort ModbusSerialPort = new SerialPort();

        ModbusSerialPort.PortName = strPortName;
        ModbusSerialPort.BaudRate = nBaudRate;
        ModbusSerialPort.DataBits = nDataBits;
        ModbusSerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        ModbusSerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;        

        ModbusSerialPort.Open();

        ModbusSerialSlave Slave;

        // Create RTU
        Slave = ModbusSerialSlave.CreateRtu(1, ModbusSerialPort);
        Slave.DataStore = DataStoreFactory.CreateDefaultDataStore();
        Slave.ModbusSlaveRequestReceived += Slave_ModbusSlaveRequestReceived;
        Slave.DataStore.DataStoreReadFrom += dataStore_DataStoreReadFrom;

        Slave.Listen();

        ReadShm.IsBackground = true;
        ReadShm.Start();
    }
    catch
    {

    }
```

Comment: You may be missing the return character (or wrong return character) or BAUD rate is wrong.  Best way of debugging a serial port is to use a tool like PUTTY and manually type the commands until you get it to work.

Comment: Please confirm which modbus package you are using (and the version of the package). There are a few that are quite similar so I don't want to guess.

Comment: @Brits I'm using NModbus4 v2.1.0

Comment: @jdweng thanks, I will try using PUTTY. What do you mean by missing the return characters?

Comment: At the end of each line there is usually a return.

Comment: @jdweng The protocol in use appears to be Modbus RTU, a binary protocol, so there is no return character (and a specialised terminal, such as minicom, is likely to be easier to work with than putty).

Comment: In NModbus4 v2.1.0 [`ModbusSerialSlave.Listen()` blocks](https://github.com/NModbus4/NModbus4/blob/2.1.0/NModbus4/Device/ModbusSerialSlave.cs#L81) so what you are seeing is to be expected. Note that NModbus 4 has not been updated since 2016 so you may want to select a supported library.

Comment: @Brits Thanks Brits, I'll consider other libraries as well. But if you look at line 121-125 of the link you shared, it seems like the timeout exception is implemented. Shouldn't that catch phrase return the exception message?

Comment: Lines 121-125 catch the exception and clears the buffer (allowing it to start looking for a new packet). The exception is not re-thrown so the loop continues... Note that I am assuming that your issue is that you are expecting `Slave.Listen();` to return (it's probably working as intended and you could make a modbus request). If the issue is something else then you will need to edit the question and add additional detail.

Comment: @Brits : The data may be binary, but most ModBus interfaces sends the data as ASCII.